# TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined in HTML5 Canvas with Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic2, html5-canvas

my home.ts looks like this

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

    export class HomePage {
      @ViewChild('canvas') canvasEl : ElementRef;
      private _CANVAS:any;
      private _CONTEXT:any;
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this._CANVAS = this.canvasEl.nativeElement;
        this._CONTEXT = this._CANVAS.getContext('2d');
      }
    }
```

this is what I have in home.html

```
 <canvas #canvas></canvas>
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.
I keep getting this error and I dont know how to solve. Could someone help me on this Thank you so much.

Comment: you might have an extra `}` in there.. can you recheck your code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the `ElementRef`, you will have to use angular lifecycle hook `ngAfterViewInit` instead of the `ionViewDidLoad` lifecycle hook.

```
export class HomePage implements AfterViewInit{
    @ViewChild('canvas') canvasEl : ElementRef;
    private _CANVAS:any;
    private _CONTEXT:any;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this._CANVAS = this.canvasEl.nativeElement;
        this._CONTEXT = this._CANVAS.getContext('2d');
    }
}
```